# Changes done in Admin are not reflecting in api results

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I'm using react starter version of  broadleafcommerce. (version 5.2 )

**Question 1:**
I added a new Category in Admin and added it to menu as well. I have changed the solr.repeat.interval option in runtime properties to 3 sec in both api, core modules. yet I do not see any new updates in the api response or in the UI.

Am I missing something ?

**Question 2:**

I dont know how to modify admin UI . I dont see any source code for it. Can you please answers these both ?

Answer (score 1):

There is database-level caching happening, you will not see your changes immediately on the frontend unless you manually expire the ehcache cache, or wait for it to expire.

You can also disable all of the database caching, see [the Broadleaf docs for more information](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/additional-configuration/caching-configuration).